# Embedding Python in C++Builder app

Tags: python, c++, c++builder

My project is to embed Python in a C++Builder application. I am using Python 3.6.

I've added Python's `Include` folder in the System Include path, and Python's `Libs` folder in the Library path:

> Tools > Environment options > C++ Options > Paths and Directories

Here is `MyUnit1.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <vcl.h>
#include <Python.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
  : TForm(Owner)
  {
  }
```

But I get this error:

> [bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp(4): E2209 Unable to open include file 'Python.h'

Comment: Not related to the error, but `#include <Python.h>` belongs after `#pragma hdrstop` instead of before it

Comment: Problem solved : INCLUDE and LIBS folders should be added this way: Project>Options>C++.

Comment: Still have trouble with inttypes.h, I have this error: [bcc32 Error] inttypes.h(251): E2171 Body has already been defined for function 'std::abs(__int64)'